# Including CSS and JS files on multilanguage sites

Tags: multi-site

Up till now, all my craft sites were single language. When including CSS and JS files from `web` folder, i used to use `{{siteUrl}}` variable, like this:

```
<script src='{{siteUrl}}/plugins/jquery.js'></script>
```

Such path was rendered to this:

```
<script src='http://website.com/plugins/jquery.js'></script>
```

Unfortunetly, on multilanguage websites, where different languages have different url path (site.com and site.com/en), `{{siteUrl}}` variable changes and paths to these files are incorrectly rendered, like this:

```
<script src='http://website.com/en/plugins/jquery.js'></script>
```

What variable can i use that will give me path to web folder - regardless of currently used language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the alias instead `{{ alias('@web') }}`

It will always point to your `web` directory